# How to pass common param through all the routes in react-router

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I have an application which searches for some items and on finding them opensup a react application in new window with some params that are item specific.Now once i have my react application opened up in new window.I want to pass those params in the url throughout my application.

I searched for it but nothing helped.

Here is an example of my scenario :
Url with which I am opening the react application :http://localhost:3000/dashboard?instrumentId=75064&username=XYZ&appleturl=http%3A%2F%2Flxsdfeat1.global.abcecorp.net%3A7950%2FrmsDPPortal%2Fresources%2Fsapplauncher.jar&dsfhosturl=http%3A%2F%2Flxbeat1.global.bcecorp.net%3A7950%2FrmsasdfPortal

I want everything after 'dashboard' to be part of all the urls in my application.so that i can extract url,usernames in all the pages and make api requests using  them.

Note: I am using react router for routing purpose

Comment: add those `query params` to each link you are hitting for transition

Answer (score 0):

I passed that common url in this way and it works for my use case.

```js
browserHistory.push(
     {
        pathname : "/calsummary",
        search : searchParams
     });
     
//or
browserHistory.push(
     {
        pathname : "/calsummary",
        search : location.search//location object is which is available on   window object,window.location
     });
```